# difference between imageview and image aspect fit ratio

Tags: ios, uiimageview, bounds, aspect-fit

I have added an Imageview on UIView, and set the property AspectToFit. According to app requirement, I need to add one more image on the imageview.

[image: iPhone 6s Plus]

```
    float width;
    float height;
    float x;
    float y;

    CGSize imageViewSize =  self.getImageView.bounds.size;// self.getImageView.frame.size;
    CGSize imageSize = self.getImage.size;
    CGFloat minFactor = imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width;
    if (imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height < minFactor)
    {
        minFactor = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height;
    }
    CGRect frame = self.getImageView.frame;
    NSLog(@"view height..%@",NSStringFromCGRect (frame));
    CGSize resultSize = CGSizeMake(minFactor * imageSize.width, minFactor * imageSize.height);
    UIImage *newimage =  [self imageWithImage:self.getImage scaledToSize:resultSize];
    float mainwidth = imageViewSize.width;
    float mainheight = imageViewSize.height;

    float imagewidth = newimage.size.width;
    float imageheight = newimage.size.height;

    _widthdiff = mainwidth-imagewidth;
    _heightdiff = mainheight-imageheight;

    x = self.view.frame.size.width-width-0-_widthdiff/2;
    y = self.view.frame.size.height-height-116-_heightdiff/2;

imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]
                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [imageview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

This code is working fine for all the devices except iPhone (iPhone 6 Plus, iPone 7 Plus). As I can see there is issue only in Plus size of devices.

Is there a different to calculate the difference or ratio between imageview and proper image?
Please advice.

Please refer attached image[image: iPhone 5s]

Comment: it is not clear what exact issue you are facing.

Comment: @Shubhank I have edited my question, attached two images, one is for iPhone 5s and other is for iPhone 6s Plus. You can see, qrcode image position is exact as per uiimage starts in uiimageview after aspect fit, but in iPhone 6s Plus, qrcode position is not correct.

Comment: where are the values of `width` and `height` assigned ?

Comment: @Shubhank it is 75*75, width 75, height 75

Answer (score 1):

We can add new image by calculating the size of old image and then add it to the UIView as per requirement.

```
    CGSize imageViewSize =   self.getImageView.frame.size;
    CGSize imageSize = self.getImage.size;
    CGFloat minFactor = imageViewSize.width / imageSize.width;
    if (imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height < minFactor)
    {
        minFactor = imageViewSize.height / imageSize.height;
    }
    CGSize resultSize = CGSizeMake(minFactor * imageSize.width, minFactor * imageSize.height);

    UIImage *newimage =  [self imageWithImage:self.getImage scaledToSize:resultSize];
self.duplicateimageview = [[UIImageView alloc]
                                   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-newimage.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2-newimage.size.height/2, newimage.size.width, newimage.size.height)];
        [self.view addSubview:self.duplicateimageview];
        self.duplicateimageview.image = newimage;    

- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image
              scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```